# I can't scrape a website where url not change on its next page when load more using requests and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**Python Beatifulsoup requests**

```
import requests
import re
import os
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup





for d in searche:
    truelink = d.replace(" ","-")
    truelinkk=('https://www.fb.com

    r = requests.get(truelinkk,headers=headers).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
    mobile=soup.find_all('li',class_='EIR5N')
```

**I am beginner to python. I can't scrape  a website where url doesn't change on its next page when load more  using requests and beautifulsoup please can someone visit the site let me know the procedure for scraping above websites using beautifulsoup and requests. Any answer would be appreciated Thankyou
Please look this link
https://www.olx.in/hyderabad_g4058526/q-Note-9-max-pro?isSearchCall=true**

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ and __scraping__ not scrap or scrapping. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Comment: Sorry thankyou i will make changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium in headless mode instead of *requests*. Eventho selenium is used for web automation it can help you in this case.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

begin = time.time()

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Since the URL doesn't change you have to click on the button that you want by getting its xpath and:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath code').click()
```

You can avoid using requests and you can get the source code of the page by using:

```
html_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
```

Comment: I don't have knowledge of selenium i am beginner still learning beautifulsoup and requests. Is not this possible with requests or beautifulsoup?

Comment: I had faced the same issue and this is how I solved it and learning selenium is pretty easy. Most of your code remains the same we just replace requests with selenium.